# How can I make bar chart with attached columns?

Tags: matlab, plot, bar-chart

How can I obtain something like pic related? I know how to use the "stacked" option but not how to make columns attached.

[image: 1]

Comment: To make the columns attached you use the second, optional argument of `bar`. Try for example `data = rand(2,3); bar(data, 1)`

Comment: There is a [function](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32884-plot-groups-of-stacked-bars) available at MATLABcentral that does what you need

Comment: @LuisMendo Thank Luis. What about if I want to obtain more than one group? Because with your code it create only one group.

Comment: I'm not sure if by "group" you mean bars attached together or bars placed on the same horizontal position. Anyway, the linked File Exchange function seems to do what you want. An alternative could be a loop: `hold on, for k = 1:2, data = rand(2,3); bar(data, 1), end`

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm having problem with the function posted because of the colors. Anyway by "group" I meant "attached". Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Furhermore doing data= rand(2,3); bar(data1,1,'stacked'); creates a group as I want but I don't know how to create a second group separated to the first.